# Handle post request with redux and rails API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby-on-rails, redux, fetch-api

I'm trying to post some data with fetch method in my API.

```
export const CREATE_MATCH = 'CREATE_MATCH'

export function createMatch(user) {
  const request = fetch("/api/matches", {

    // Adding method type
    method: "POST",


    // Adding headers to the request
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        "X-User-Token": user.authentication_token,
        "X-User-Email": user.email
    }
  })

  return {
    type: CREATE_MATCH,
    payload: request
  }
}
```

but the I only get the response and not the data created

> Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/api/matches", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}

I don't know how to get the data created.

In rails this is what I have, I don't have any data in a Match, only id and timestamps.

```
def create
  @match = Match.new
  authorize @match
  if @match.save
    render json: @match
  else
    render_error
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

i've just find an answer with async / await function

```
export async function createMatch(user) {
 const request = await fetch("/api/matches", {

   // Adding method type
   method: "POST",

   // Adding body or contents to send
   // body: JSON.stringify(),

   // Adding headers to the request
   headers: {
       "Content-type": "application/json",
       "X-User-Token": user.authentication_token,
       "X-User-Email": user.email
   }
 })
 const match = await request.json();
 console.log(match)

 return {
   type: CREATE_MATCH,
   payload: match
 }
}
```